# snake not eating food

Tags: python

I'm working on a simple Snake game in Python using curses, and I'm having an issue with the snake not properly eating the food. The snake seems to move over the food, but it doesn't get longer. Can someone please help me identify what's causing this issue and how I can fix it?

```py
import curses
from random import randint

def create_food(snake, box):
    food = None
    while food is None:
        food = [randint(box[0]+1, box[1]-1), randint(box[2]+1, box[3]-1)]
        if food in snake:
            food = None
    return food

def main(stdscr):
    curses.curs_set(0)
    stdscr.timeout(100)

    sh, sw = stdscr.getmaxyx()
    w = curses.newwin(sh, sw, 0, 0)
    w.keypad(1)

    box = [3, sh-3, 3, sw-3]
    snake = [
        [sh//2, sw//2],
        [sh//2, sw//2-1],
        [sh//2, sw//2-2]
    ]

    food = create_food(snake, box)

    key = curses.KEY_RIGHT

    while True:
        next_key = w.getch()
        key = key if next_key == -1 else next_key

        head = [snake[0][0], snake[0][1]]

        if key == curses.KEY_DOWN:
            head[0] += 1
        elif key == curses.KEY_UP:
            head[0] -= 1
        elif key == curses.KEY_LEFT:
            head[1] -= 1
        elif key == curses.KEY_RIGHT:
            head[1] += 1

        snake.insert(0, head)

        if head == food:
            food = None
        else:
            tail = snake.pop()

        w.addch(food[0], food[1], curses.ACS_PI)

        w.addch(tail[0], tail[1], ' ')

        w.addch(snake[0][0], snake[0][1], '*')

        if (
            snake[0][0] in [box[0], box[1]] or
            snake[0][1] in [box[2], box[3]] or
            snake[0] in snake[1:]
        ):
            break

curses.wrapper(main)
```

i need the snake to get longer when eats food

Comment: At the point in your script where ```if head == food:``` is True, you need to increase the length of the snake.

Comment: I see the code to draw the new head position and remove the old tail position during movement, but when is the remainder of the snake's body initially drawn?  I don't have a setup to test curses right now, but this looks to me like you're only ever drawing the head segment.

Answer (score 0):

You did `if head == food: food = None` but you also need to add something to make the snake longer at the tail.

Comment: The growth should already be handled by the fact that when the food is eaten, the tail piece is not popped with `snake.pop()`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Answer (score 0):

So, after getting curses running in Windows (and figuring that going left first ends the game immediately), the problem I'm finding isn't that the snake doesn't get longer, but that the program crashes after you eat the food with the error `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable` after you get the food, and when it reaches the line `w.addch(food[0], food[1], curses.ACS_PI)`

The solution is to change this:

```
        if head == food:
            food = None
        else:
            tail = snake.pop()
```

To this:

```
        if head == food:
            food = create_food(snake, box)
        else:
            tail = snake.pop()
```